# How can I transform an array of characters with a few lines of code to a data.frame?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have the following array
`my_list <- c("Jan-01--Dec-31|00:00--24:00", "Jan-01--Jun-30|12:00--18:00",
             "Jul-06--Dec-31|09:00--19:00")`

What is the shortest code which results in:

```
  x1     x2     x3
1 Jan-01 Jan-01 Jul-06
2 Dec-31 Jun-30 Dec-31
```

and

```
  x2    x2    x3
1 00:00 12:00 09:00
2 24:00 18:00 19:00
```

**At the moment I have the (not very nice) code**

```
df <- as.data.frame(strsplit(my_list, split = "|", fixed = T),
                    stringsAsFactors = F)
date_list <- strsplit(as.character(df[1, ]), split = "--", fixed = T)
date_df <- as.data.frame(date_list, col.names = c(1:length(date_list)),
                         stringsAsFactors = F)
time_list <- strsplit(as.character(df[2, ]), split = "--", fixed = T)
time_df <- as.data.frame(time_list, col.names = c(1:length(date_list)),
                         stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**The best thing I have up to now is**

```
date_list <- sapply(strsplit(schedule$schedule, split = "|", fixed = T), "[", 1)
date_df <- t(data.frame(x1=sapply(strsplit(df1, split = "--", fixed = T), "[", 1),
                   x2=sapply(strsplit(df1, split = "--", fixed = T), "[", 2),
                   stringsAsFactors = F))
# and similarly for time_list and time_df.
```

Is there something more elegant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tstrsplit` from `data.table` package and `str_split_fixed` from `stringr` are pretty useful functions to get correct shaped data when splitting vectors of strings; The former provides `transpose` of the splitted string which allows you to extract the date and time separately without using `apply` function and the latter split strings into matrix with specified columns:

```
library(data.table); library(stringr)
lapply(tstrsplit(my_list, "\\|"), function(s) t(str_split_fixed(s, "--", 2)))

#[[1]]
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
#[1,] "Jan-01" "Jan-01" "Jul-06"
#[2,] "Dec-31" "Jun-30" "Dec-31"

#[[2]]
#     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
#[1,] "00:00" "12:00" "09:00"
#[2,] "24:00" "18:00" "19:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_results <- sapply(strsplit(my_list,"|",fixed=T),function(x) strsplit(x,"--",fixed=T))
my_dates <- t(Reduce("rbind",myresults[1,]))
my_times <- t(Reduce("rbind",myresults[2,]))
```

Comment: I like that you don't need any additional package.

Answer (score 2):

`strsplit` accepts a greppish pattern that can do the split in one pass.  Then can use `lapply` (or `sapply`) and finish up with `setNames`.

```
 setNames( data.frame(lapply( strsplit( my_vec, split="\\-\\-|\\|"),  "[", 1:2) ), paste0("x",1:3) )

      x1     x2     x3
1 Jan-01 Jan-01 Jul-06
2 Dec-31 Jun-30 Dec-31
```

Obviously the times could be handled by substituting 3:4 for 1:2 in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
a <- t(str_split_fixed(my_list, "\\||--", 4))

#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
#[1,] "Jan-01" "Jan-01" "Jul-06"
#[2,] "Dec-31" "Jun-30" "Dec-31"
#[3,] "00:00"  "12:00"  "09:00" 
#[4,] "24:00"  "18:00"  "19:00"
```

To get the final output, `data.frame(a[1:2,])` and `data.frame(a[3:4,])`

**Update**

```
my_list <- "Jan-01--Dec-31|00:00--24:00"
a <- t(str_split_fixed(my_list, "\\||--", 4))

     [,1]    
[1,] "Jan-01"
[2,] "Dec-31"
[3,] "00:00" 
[4,] "24:00"

data.frame(a[1:2,])

  a.1.2...
1   Jan-01
2   Dec-31

data.frame(a[3:4,])

  a.3.4...
1    00:00
2    24:00
```

Comment: What can I do in case of `my_list <- "Jan-01--Dec-31|00:00--24:00"`? It seems it does not work then...

Comment: You are right, but I give parameter `b <- a[1:2, ]` to another function. This function then tries to access `c <- b[1, ]` which throws the error. Is there a trivial workaround?

Comment: So you are trying to access the first row of `b`. In this case, the first row has only one element, and `c` will be a vector of length 1 instead of being a vector of length x. May be you can check the length of `c`, i.e. `if(length(c) > 1)` before performing some operation on it?

Comment: Ok. I also thought about that. Let me see how I proceed. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option

```
lst <- strsplit(scan(text=my_list, sep="|", what ="", quiet=TRUE), "--")
do.call(cbind, lst[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
#[1,] "Jan-01" "Jan-01" "Jul-06"
#[2,] "Dec-31" "Jun-30" "Dec-31"

do.call(cbind, lst[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
#     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
#[1,] "00:00" "12:00" "09:00"
#[2,] "24:00" "18:00" "19:00"
```

---

Or in a single line `base R` option

```
lapply(split(scan(text=my_list, sep="|", what ="", quiet=TRUE), 1:2), 
                      function(x) do.call(cbind, strsplit(x, "--")))
#$`1`
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
#[1,] "Jan-01" "Jan-01" "Jul-06"
#[2,] "Dec-31" "Jun-30" "Dec-31"

#$`2`
#    [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
#[1,] "00:00" "12:00" "09:00"
#[2,] "24:00" "18:00" "19:00"
```